# c# regular expression - different conditions for one string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, winforms

I need a regular expression for the below requirement:

```
1)Should be 7 characters in length
2)At least any one of the last two characters should be an alphabet[a-zA-Z]
```

I got stuck in implementing the second rule. Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Show what you have so far.

Comment: `if(input.Length ==7 && input.Skip(5).Any(c=>char.IsLetter(c))){//success}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
"^.{5}(?:[a-zA-Z].|.[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]{2})$"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex ([demo](http://rubular.com/r/cZnnJpp2Gj))

```
^.{5}([a-zA-Z].{1}|.{1}[a-zA-Z])$
```